# Canvas wont draw anything - React, Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, web-parts

I am totally new to TS and I am trying to do some simple drawing with canvas. I get no errors but nothing is showed not even the console log that is inside function.

```
function gameLoader() {
  const gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
  var ctx = gameCanvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
  console.log(document.getElementById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx"));
}

export default class SnakeTheGame extends React.Component<
  ISnakeTheGameProps,
  {}
> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<ISnakeTheGameProps> {
    return (
      <div className={styles.snakeTheGame} id="gameWindow">
        <canvas
          id={"gameCanvas"}
          height="500px"
          width="500px"
          onLoad={() => gameLoader()}
        ></canvas>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I just don't know how to fix it. I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: Is `SnakeTheGame` being rendered by anything? Is your app being rendered into the DOM?

Comment: Yes Canvas is there with correct size and ID. (is sharepoint webpart)

Comment: Use a ref, don't use getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try below code:

```html
export default class Testcanvas extends React.Component<ITestcanvasProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<ITestcanvasProps> {
    return (
      <div className={styles.testcanvas}>
        <canvas
          ref="canvas"
          height="500px"
          width="500px"
        ></canvas>
      </div>
    );
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.gameLoader();
  }

  private gameLoader(): void {
    const ctx = (this.refs.canvas as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx");
  }
```

Test Result:

[image]

BR

Answer (score 1):

canvas onload only fires when it loads smth, so if you put your loader function in onload, it will never be ran

heres a possible solution

```js
function gameLoader(gameCanvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
  var ctx = gameCanvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
  console.log(document.getElementById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx"));
}

export default class SnakeTheGame extends React.Component<
  ISnakeTheGameProps,
  {}
> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<ISnakeTheGameProps> {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>();
    useEffect(() => gameLoader(ref.current), []);
    return (
      <div className={styles.snakeTheGame} id="gameWindow">
        <canvas
          ref={ref}
          height="500px"
          width="500px"
        ></canvas>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. Sorry, I was not here for some time. I get few errors trying this but now I understand canvas onLoad. Thank you very much for your time.